# Using naturality to prove $f: \forall\alpha. \alpha\times\alpha\to\alpha$ must be a projection

Tags: programming-languages, lambda-calculus, category-theory

Suppose we have a System F term $f : \forall \alpha. \alpha\times\alpha\to\alpha$, interpreted in a parametric model which is a bicartesian closed category.

I was wondering if in such context it is possible to prove that (in the model) $f$ must be a projection (either $\pi_1$ or $\pi_2$), exploiting the naturality of $f$ and little else.

So far, I got the following sketch.

By naturality, for all $g: A\to B$, we have
$$ (g \times g); f_B = f_A ; g$$
In particular, we can take $A = 2 = 1+1$ (the coproduct of the final object with itself), and take ${\sf tt},{\sf ff}: 1\to 2$ to be the inclusions.

We get that, for all $g: 1\to B$, we have
$$ \langle {\sf tt}, {\sf ff} \rangle ; (g \times g); f_B = 
   \langle {\sf tt}, {\sf ff} \rangle ; f_2 ; g$$
Now, we have a morphism
$$ h = \langle {\sf tt}, {\sf ff} \rangle ; f_2 : 1 \to 2 $$
and we assume that (*) in the model $h$ must be one of $\sf tt,ff$ -- i.e., that no other morphisms exist.

W.l.o.g., assume $h=\sf tt$ (the other case being symmetrical). Then, we have
$$ \langle {\sf tt};g , {\sf ff};g \rangle ; f_B = 
   {\sf tt} ; g$$
and, taking $g = [m,n]$ for some $m,n : 1\to B$
$$ \langle m , n \rangle ; f_B = m$$
which is "close" to stating that $f_B$ is the first projection.

Questions:

1) Can we weaken the assumption ($*$) in some way? 
Or, can we strengthen ($*$) by requiring some standard property that "usually" holds in known models?
I mean, I could work in a specific model (e.g. PERs) where we only have two inclusions $1\to 2$, but maybe there's some more general standard-ish assumption which can guarantee that?

2) Can we prove that $f_B$ is really a projection? Proving that it is such seems to require a sort of extensionality principle like

$$ (\forall x:1\to A. x;f=x;g) \implies f=g $$

but this, I guess, might not hold in general.

A final note: I'm aware that one can prove $f$ to be $\beta\eta$ equivalent to a projection through syntactic means (Krivine does so, if I remember correctly), but I am really interested in the consequences of naturality.

Comment: I suspect you'll need more than naturality. Consider $\mathbf{Set}^2\simeq\mathbf{Set}\times\mathbf{Set}$. It is a complete and cocomplete Boolean Grothendieck topos with NNO. It has natural transformations $\Delta\to Id$ beyond the projections, namely taking the inner or outer sets of each pair of sets. $X\times X$ being a pair of pairs of sets in $\mathbf{Set}^2$.

Comment: @DerekElkins Ah, that's a good reasonably simple example (even if I'm not yet familiar with topoi), thanks. I also believe I need more than naturality, but perhaps not so much more. At the moment ($*$) plus extensionality is the best (in my very own opinion) sufficient criterion I could find. But maybe there's something even simpler or more standard (?)

Comment: Note that (famously) [$\mathbf{Set}$ is *not* a model of System F](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00076261/document). However, my point was that if you consider any class of categories that contains $\mathbf{Set}^2$, e.g. you consider, say, [lextensive categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extensive+category) then the statement won't hold. Now there are properties that exclude $\mathbf{Set}^2$ and include $\mathbf{Set}$ (for which the statement does hold) such as being two-valued, and there are properties that exclude both such as being a model of System F, requiring all of parametricity.

Comment: @DerekElkins Sure. The only parametric System F models I read about so far are PER-based models, so I was trying to generalize a bit fomr there. Even if $\bf Set$-derived categories necessarily fail in being models (as Reynolds proved), it is interesting to see what happens there.

Comment: Agreed. My previous comment was to avoid a possible confusion that I was presenting $\mathbf{Set}^2$ as a counter-model that demonstrates that the statement couldn't possibly be generally true (and explain what I was trying to accomplish with that example.) It sounds like you understand this completely. It may be useful context for others.

Answer (score 0):

Naturality is sufficient.

An easy way is to use the Yoneda lemma, which gives the equivalence:

$$ a\times a\to a \equiv  (\mathbb2 \to a ) \to a \equiv \mathbb2 $$
where $\mathbb2$ denotes the Boolean type and it is assumed that the arrow $a\times a\to a$ is a natural transformation.

We can adapt the proof of the Yoneda lemma to this case and find a simple proof from naturality:

Suppose $$p : \forall a.\,a \times a \to a$$ is a function implemented somehow in System F, and suppose $p$ obeys its naturality law. (That assumption will follow from parametricity, but that's not the question here.) Set the type parameter as $a = \mathbb2$ and apply $p$ to the specially chosen value $x : \mathbb 2 \times \mathbb 2$, namely, $x = (true, false)$. The value $p(x)$ is again of type $\mathbb2$ and so we must have $p(x)=y$ where the Boolean value $y$ is either $y=false$ or $y=true$.

Now, use the naturality law of $p$: For any types $a$, $b$, any values $m:a$, $n:a$, and any function $f: a\to b$ we must have:
$$ p(f(m), f(n)) = f(p(m, n))$$
Choose $a=\mathbb2$, $m=true$, $n=false$, but keep the type $b$ arbitrary. Then the naturality law says:
$$ p(f(true), f(false)) = f(p(true, false)) = f(y) $$

This naturality law constrains $p$ enough to force $p = \pi_1$ or $p = \pi_2$. This is because  $f(true)$ and $f(false)$ are arbitrary values of type $b$. Denote them by $b_1 = f(true)$ and $b_2 = f(false)$. We know that $y$ is either true or false. Suppose $y=false$. Then we have found that for arbitrary values $b_1$, $b_2$ of type $b$:
$$ p(b_1, b_2) = f(false)=b_2$$
Similarly, if $y=true$ then for arbitrary values $b_1$, $b_2$ of type $b$:
$$ p(b_1, b_2) = f(true)=b_1$$

We have shown that either  $p = \pi_1$ or $p = \pi_2$.